# One of my W2 employees quit my repair shop in NYC, do I need to do anything on my end to alert the state/city?

Tags: taxes, new-york, payroll-taxes, payroll

I have a repair shop and one W2 employee. He just quit last month. Do I need to alert the State or City about payroll taxes or payroll insurance company that my guy left? I'm not sure if I need to do anything on my end as an employer.

Comment: While this is a good question I fail to see how it has anything to do with personal finance and/or money.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about running a company